# Angular 2 + ngrx(redux) + forms

Tags: forms, angular, redux, rxjs

How do you handle Angular 2 forms in unidirectional data flow? Especially with validation between several parent/child components?

I am using ngrx/store and model driven forms with form builder.. Is it possible to do something similar like form reducer in React and make it as a part of Store?

Do you have some articles about it?

Comment: I'm using ngrx, but not doing form validation as such. I decided to leave ngModel to do its business (mutating away...) unhindered. I use the submit button to send data to the store and trigger changes to the rest of the App

Comment: You could use store in combination with model driven forms. Check out this great article about it: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html

Comment: I'm also looking for a nice example, there are tons of tutorials and blogs on forms and ngrx but not together.

Comment: you ever get some clarity here?

Comment: I wrote an article on this topic, its very easy to do with @angular-redux/form https://www.el-davo.com/articles/9e1fa660-73a2-11e7-b9ea-29a5f4e71be5

Answer (score 15):

I have created a library called [ngrx-forms](https://github.com/MrWolfZ/ngrx-forms) that does exactly what you want. You can get it on npm via:

```
npm install ngrx-forms --save
```

I recommend checking out the full README on the github page, but below you can find some examples of what you need to do to get the library up and running once installed.

Import the module:

```
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { NgrxFormsModule } from 'ngrx-forms';

import { reducers } from './reducer';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    NgrxFormsModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Add a group state somewhere in your state tree via `createFormGroupState` and call the `formGroupReducer` inside your reducer:

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { FormGroupState, createFormGroupState, formGroupReducer } from 'ngrx-forms';

export interface MyFormValue {
  someTextInput: string;
  someCheckbox: boolean;
  nested: {
    someNumber: number;
  };
}

const FORM_ID = 'some globally unique string';

const initialFormState = createFormGroupState<MyFormValue>(FORM_ID, {
  someTextInput: '',
  someCheckbox: false,
  nested: {
    someNumber: 0,
  },
});

export interface AppState {
  someOtherField: string;
  myForm: FormGroupState<MyFormValue>;
}

const initialState: AppState = {
  someOtherField: '',
  myForm: initialFormState,
};

export function appReducer(state = initialState, action: Action): AppState {
  const myForm = formGroupReducer(state.myForm, action);
  if (myForm !== state.myForm) {
    state = { ...state, myForm };
  }

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'some action type':
      // modify state
      return state;

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

Expose the form state inside your component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { FormGroupState } from 'ngrx-forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { MyFormValue } from './reducer';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html',
})
export class MyComponent {
  formState$: Observable<FormGroupState<MyFormValue>>;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.formState$ = store.select(s => s.myForm);
  }
}
```

Set the control states in your template:

```
<form novalidate [ngrxFormState]="(formState$ | async)">
  <input type="text"
         [ngrxFormControlState]="(formState$ | async).controls.someTextInput">

  <input type="checkbox"
         [ngrxFormControlState]="(formState$ | async).controls.someCheckbox">

  <input type="number"
         [ngrxFormControlState]="(formState$ | async).controls.nested.controls.someNumber">
</form>
```

Comment: Just wanted to say... I love this library - thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 10):

This is a fairly old question, but I couldn't find a great solution in my own quest for working with ngrx + reactive forms in Angular. As a result, I'll post my research here with hope that it may help someone else. My solution can be broken down into two parts, and I pray you (oh weathered soul) find it applicable to your problem:

1) Monitor the form element/s (for example, "keyup" event for a typical text input), and update the State from that event. This strategy comes straight out of the [book search component](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/components/book-search.ts) in the [ngrx example app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app). We can now successfully populate the State as our form changes. Awesome! 50% done!

2) The angular [reactive forms guide](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) demonstrates creating the form group in the constructor. I have seen some other people do it inside ngOnInit, but this is too late in the lifecycle for our needs (I tried, I failed). Now that we have our form group established, setup ngOnChanges to capture any changes pushed from the state, and then update the form group using [patchValue](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#populate-the-form-model-with-setvalue-and-patchvalue). For example:

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.valueICareAbout1) {
      this.myForm.patchValue({
        valueICareAbout1: changes.valueICareAbout1.currentValue
      });
    }
    if (changes.valueICareAbout2) {
      this.myForm.patchValue({
        valueICareAbout2: changes.valueICareAbout2.currentValue
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

In the applications I built with Angular 2, the following guideline seemed to work well:

Parent components pass data down to children via data binding. Child components request data changes by emitting output events to parent components. It is the parent components responsibility to act accordingly.

In a hierarchical component structure, data changes are handled by the lowest component that depends on the data. If there's another component higher up or a sibling that depends on the same data item, pass changes up by emitting events and leave the handling to a higher component.

This scheme works well because, for any data that is relevant to more than one component, there is a single component responsible for performing changes. Changes bubble down automatically. Components are reusable, and changes in the component tree can be easily adapted.

With regard to validation, any component in the ladder between the lowest component emitting a data change request up to the highest component that finally handles the change, any component can effectively cancel the change by not passing it higher up. In most applications, I'd opt for validating data changes at the origin of the change though.

Naturally, child components can still have internal state and need not communicate changes - unless changes are relevant to the parent component.

Answer (score 3):

Form data is inherently a very local state, especially for Angular since ngModel binds to local component variables. The top devs that I know recommend keeping the data for the form localized to that component (ie just use ngModel with local variables). This is because un-submitted form data is almost never shared by various components across your whole application. When the user submits the form then you can dispatch an action with a payload containing the form data to a parent component, to the store, or even to an ngrx/effect to be posted to a server.

Comment: Yeah ? Localized ? Look into Elm - all application parts should be a shape of state

Comment: Sharing data between components is only one of the benefits of a single state store. This cannot be a complete answer.

Comment: @YuriyYakovenko It is unnecessary to save things only relevant to one remote corner of your app in the application-level state. This was not a questino about Elm. It was a question about Angular 2, and the way Angular 2 handles forms you almost have to bind to things in the controller- ie local state.

Comment: Im not sure I agree with the statement about " Most top devs recommend keeping the data for the form localized to that component ". I can see why if your using vanilla redux you could do it the way you have suggested, however when you start to use advanced features such as sagas or epics then sharing state between the component and the epic is kind of critical. It means you dont have to send your form in the dispatched action to the epic. As the form is already in state your epic can just read from the form stored in state. simples

Comment: I dont agree with this solution nor philiosophy. It's just an opnionated view